# UIDatePicker does not show everything

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Here is My Image....
[image]

The `UIDatePicker` seems to not show everything on the screen.
Any solutions on making the font size smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html), I guess we cannot.

> You cannot customize the appearance of date
>   pickers.

A workaround is you can customize a `UIPickerView` work as a date picker and then change the font size by using `UIPickerViewDelegate` something like:

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var label: UILabel

        if let view = view as? UILabel {
            label = view
        } else {
            label = UILabel()
        }

        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)

        label.text = recheckDayOptions[row].toString()

        return label
    }
```

Comment: ok... but do u have any suggestions on this kind of problems?

Comment: Increasing the width of your popover could also help